# How to show the gnome3 activities menu only on the monitor where it was triggered?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

**Additional information:**

Whenever the gnome3 activities menu is triggered (e.g. when I'm using the gnome search tool to search for a program) the menus effect is triggered on all monitors e.g. showing all open windows for each monitor. I find this very annoying.

The following screenshot shows what I don't want, since I triggered the menu on the screen in the middle the activities menus effect should only be shown here.

[image]

**Question:**

Is there a way to show the activities menu only on the monitor where it was triggered ? (leaving the windows on the other monitors as they are)